# Trouble joining tables in springboot with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, controller

I probably still have a lot to learn but I've gone threw many examples given on the web with no luck. I simply want to create a @jointable

My Models are

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserLogin")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="UserID")
    private long userID;
    @Column(name="email", nullable = false, unique=true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;



@Entity
@Table(name = "Menu")
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ItemID")
    private long itemID;
    @Column(name = "Item_Name")
    private String item_Name;
    @Column(name = "Item_Price")
    private float item_Price;
    @Column(name = "Item_Points")
    private int item_Points;
    @Column(name = "Item_Calories")
    private int item_Calories;
    @Column(name = "Item_Discount")
    private float item_Discount;
```

I have already created CRUD functions in the controller for the menu entities but want to create an Add button so customers can store items in there account with the table

```
create table UserOrder(
EmployeeID INT not null,
ItemID int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES UserLogin(EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Menu(ItemID)
)
```

How do I create the controller for the Add button? or do I simply write my own query in the repository?
Thanks if anyone can help, I can link project as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you doing this is called **one to many mapping with join table** so you don't need to create table manually in db.

as below:

```
@Table(name = "UserLogin")
@Entity
public class User {
.
.
.
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="USER_ORDER", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="userId")}
, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ItemID", referencedColumnName="ItemID")})
private Set<Menu> items;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Menu")
public class Menu {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ItemID")
private long itemID;
......  
.....


}
```

Ref:https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-using-annotations/